# sagemaker custom @step decorator throws "TypeError: Pipeline variables do not support __str__ operation. Please use `.to_string()`"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am creating a model card step in my sagemaker pipeline, so I have defined my model_card method like below:

```
def create_model_card(model_package_details, bucket):
        import sagemaker
        model_card_name = "TestingModelCard"
        sagemaker_session = sagemaker.session.Session()

        Get model package details
        mp_details = ModelPackage.from_model_package_arn(
            model_package_arn=model_package_details,
            sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
        )

        print(f"Model Package ARN: {model_package_details}")

        my_card = ModelCard(
            name=model_card_name,
            status=ModelCardStatusEnum.PENDING_REVIEW,
            model_package_details=mp_details,
            sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session
        )
        my_card.create()
        return f"Model card {model_card_name} and package arn {model_package_details} created successfully"
```

now in my pipeline as per `[documentation][1]` calling step like this :

```
model_card_pipeline_params = {"model_package_details": model_package_arn_ref, "bucket": default_bucket}

step_delayed_model_card = function_step.step(_func=create_model_card(**model_card_pipeline_params),
                                                 security_group_ids=network_config.security_group_ids,
                                                 subnets=network_config.subnets,
                                                 role=role,
                                                 name="CreateModelCard",
                                                 instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge")
```

PS: model_package_details is the Model package ARN as output from my lambdastep before.
with this I'm getting this error

```
step_delayed_model_card = function_step.step(_func=create_model_card(**model_card_pipeline_params),
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipelines/abalone/pipeline.py", line 302, in create_model_card
    mp_details = ModelPackage.from_model_package_arn(
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/model_card/model_card.py", line 462, in from_model_package_arn
    model_package_response = cls.call_describe_model_package(
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/model_card/model_card.py", line 378, in call_describe_model_package
    model_package_response = sagemaker_session.sagemaker_client.describe_model_package(
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 553, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 962, in _make_api_call
    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1036, in _convert_to_request_dict
    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 381, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 102, in generate_report
    error_messages.append(self._format_error(error))
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/validate.py", line 125, in _format_error
    f'Invalid type for parameter {name}, value: {param}, '
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sagemaker/workflow/entities.py", line 90, in __str__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Pipeline variables do not support __str__ operation. Please use `.to_string()` to convert it to string type in execution time or use `.expr` to translate it to Json for display purpose in Python SDK.
```

Comment: Can you share your entire set of code for this please? Does not seem like you have defined the @step decorator, have you also created the config.yaml?